# How to test saltminion connectivity to saltmaster without refreshing pillar?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a monitoring script that calls `salt-call --skip-grains test.ping` on the minion. The minion seems to refresh pillar when it connects to the saltmaster. I have custom pillars which takes longer than I would like to load. Is there a way to skip refreshing pillar?

I've tried using the `--pillar-root` flag pointing to a empty pillar directory, `salt-call --skip-grains --pillar-root /root/local_custom_pillar test.ping` but this doesn't seem to do anything unless I use the `--local` flag. But I don't want to use the `--local` flag because I want to test if the saltminion is able to connect to the saltmaster.

Maybe I'm approaching this problem incorrectly; is there a better way to just test if the salt-minion can connect to the salt-master?

Running salt 3000.9

edit:
Something like this but have saltmaster return a specific response.

```
    salt.transport.client.ReqChannel.factory(minion_config)
    load = {'cmd': '_return', 'id': minion_id, 'ret':True}
    channel.send(load)
```

Comment: The `salt-call` tool and the `salt-minion` service are separate and do not interact with each other. Do you want to know if it _could_ connect or if it _is_ connected? And what level of connection - a basic TCP socket. an authenticated Salt connection, or the ability to do something in particular?

Comment: @OrangeDog I want to know if it's connected; have the minion send a message and the saltmaster send a response back. Essentially `salt-call test.ping` but without all the extra stuff where the minion sync it's grains and pillar.

I'm steering towards using a python script like below, but I'm not sure how to get the master to return something more specific than an empty dictionary since there's no associated job to return a response to.  
```
    salt.transport.client.ReqChannel.factory(minion_config)
    load = {'cmd': '_return', 'id': minion_id, 'ret':True}
    channel.send(load)
```

Comment: My answer tells you if it's connected. `salt-call` tells you nothing about the `salt-minion`. All `test.ping` does is `return True`. If there's no job then it goes nowhere.

Comment: The correct way of monitoring master-minion connections is from the master, with e.g. `salt-run manage.status`.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the minion is currently connected to the master:

```bash
ss -nt | grep '\b4505\b'
```

To be completely sure that it is the minion, run as root with the `-p` flag and check that the pid belongs to one of the minion's processes.

There is also a config setting, [`ping_interval`](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#ping-interval), you can use to force the minion to retry lost connections even when it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

On the same idea as mentionned by @OrangeDog previously.

You could use commands from `salt.runners.manage` referenced at this [page](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.manage.html) which clearly mention

> no command will be sent to minions

like :

- salt.runners.manage.alived
- salt.runners.manage.not_alived
- salt-run manage.list_state
- salt-run manage.list_not_state
- salt.runners.manage.present
- salt.runners.manage.not_present
- ...